# Number 1 haircut

Tags: vocabulaire, coiffure

I'm really new to French, as I've been living in France for a couple of weeks only. So I want to get a haircut that in many countries is called a #1 haircut, which is essentially the next-shortest after 0, but I've no idea how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show a picture. They usually have glossy catalogues with all sorts of haircuts.

Comment: What is a “#1 haircut”? Is that the same thing as what Wikipedia references under [induction cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_cut)? Is that phrase used anywhere outside the US?

Comment: Une coupe para?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would ask for:

> Une coupe à la tondeuse, sabot de 3 mm (ou 2,5 mm)

Comment: thanks, this may be helpful) it seems there is no specific grading for this in France

Comment: though you *rarely* ask for it in France, there's a grading, which is the "sabot" as said in the answer. Usually the grade used is in mils, which makes it a 2.54mm step here… So I guess you'll have to choose a bit longer or a bit shorter but you won't be able to have the same length as in the US.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is about France, I want to add some information for the Quebec province. Here in Quebec, we use the exact same system for clippers. So you could just ask something along:

> Je voudrais me faire raser au [numéro] 1

Comment: That would puzzle a haidresser in France. "Raser" is for the beard unless you specify something else "les cheveux, la moustache or whatever" and "au numero 1" is AFAIK unused here.

Comment: @jlliagre that's why I specified for Québec!

Comment: That's why I specified "in France" ;-)

Comment: *au numéro 1* could be also not clear for the coiffeur. I would specify using millimeters unless you are not afraid of a 1 mm cut!

Comment: @LaurentG. Never heard anybody asking for haircuts in millimeters here in Quebec